# Estimate segment indexes in Parallel.For

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

In the parallel for loop below, is there a reliable way to determine how many threads will be created and with what index boundaries?

```
Parallel.For
(
    0,
    int.MaxValue,
    new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism=Environment.ProcessorCount},
    (i) =>
    {
        // Monitor [i] to see how the range is segmented.
    }
);
```

If processor count on the target machine is 4 and we use all 4 processors, I observe that 4 segments are created roughly equal in size, each being approximately int.MaxValue/4. However, this is just observation and Parallel.For may or may not offer deterministic segmentation.

Searching around did not help much either. Is it possible to predict or calculate this?

Comment: What is the application that has int.MaxValue operations to perform?

Comment: int.MaxValue is just to use for this example. My actual algorithm deals with numbers iterations beyond even long.Count.

Comment: OK what is the specific problem?

Comment: Well, take an array of 1000 elements. When the above loop is called, we know it will launch 4 threads fairly reliably. What we don't know is whether each thread will get 250 elements evenly and what the starting index [i] will be for each thread. This is essentially what I want to fond out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can specify your own partitioner if you don't like the default behavior.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx)

Comment: How do you use a partitioner in `Parallel.For()`? Or do you mean the solution is to switch to `Parallel.ForEach()`?